# QGIS LecoS edge length

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, statistics, landscape

I am using the LecoS plugin to analyze areas I have previously mapped. The problem is, that these maps are square, which means, that the areas inside are cut. e.g. the forest continues but I have only mapped it until the square ends. Now LecoS does also add these cut edges to edge length. Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: Convert to lines, remove the unwanted edges, then calculate.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I would have thought that with lines, things like edge density wouldn´t be calculateable anymore, but I was wrong!